# What is the Excel Popup from F2 in ready mode?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I stumbled on this behavior in Excel: pressing F2 (without any shift key) opens a slider bar that fades in a few seconds. At first I thought F2 editing was broken, but I see this only happens in Ready mode. What is this and what can you do with?

[image: F2 Ready Slider Popup]

Comment: That slider in your picture seems to be the volume control.

Comment: Do you use laptop? Add FN key with F2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to press Fn Key along with F2 key.

In some computer models (Dell, HP), the function key is to be used along with Fn key. However, you may change this default behavior by pressing Fn + ESC.

Comment: How can this be changed?

Comment: Press FN+Esc. I have edited the answer.